# Has anyone installed VS 2008 AFTER VS 2010 Beta 1?

Tags: visual-studio

I know that it's OK to install VS 2010 B1 on a system with VS 2008 already installed.

Has anyone installed in the reverse order? Any issues or problems?

Comment: OS: Hyper-V VM with Windows 7 RC installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I had was that project files kept opening with VS 2010 even after setting it to open them with VS 2008.Not a big deal,after I killed explorer.exe it worked just fine.